# Draw Tank in Certain Place

Tags: python, pygame

Currently, I am trying to make my tank to draw in the designated place that I have written in my code.

Code:

```
import pygame, assetloader
from pygame.locals import *
import random, time, math
import pygame

GRAD = math.pi/180
blue = (0, 0, 255)

wallRects = []

maze = [[] for i in range(25)] 

assetloader.set_asset_path("assets/")

def generateMaze():
    global grid
    width  = 12
    height = 12
    seed   = time.time()

    random.seed(seed)

    grid = [[0 for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

    N, S, E, W = 1, 2, 4, 8
    DX         = { E: 1, W: -1, N: 0, S: 0 }
    DY         = { E: 0, W:  0, N: -1, S: 1 }
    OPPOSITE   = { E: W, W:  E, N: S, S: N }

    def carve_passages_from(cx, cy, grid):
        directions = random.sample([N, S, E, W], 4)

        for direction in directions:
            nx, ny = cx + DX[direction], cy + DY[direction]

            if (ny >= 0 and ny <= len(grid) - 1) and (nx >= 0 and nx <= len(grid[0]) - 1) and grid[ny][nx] == 0:
                grid[cy][cx] += direction
                grid[ny][nx] += OPPOSITE[direction]
                carve_passages_from(nx, ny, grid)

    carve_passages_from(0, 0, grid)

    global maze
    maze[0] = [2 for i in range(25)]
    mrow = 1

    # 0 = path
    # 1 = vertical wall
    # 2 = horizontal wall
    for y in range(height):
        row1 = maze[mrow]
        row2 = maze[mrow+1]
        row1.append(1)
        row2.append(1)
        for x in range(width):
            if grid[y][x] & S != 0:
                row1.append(0)
                row2.append(0)
            else:
                row1.append(0)
                row2.append(2)
            if grid[y][x] & E != 0:
                if (grid[y][x] | grid[y][x+1]) & S != 0:
                    row1.append(0)
                    row2.append(0)
                else:
                    row1.append(0)
                    row2.append(2)
            else:
                row1.append(1)
                if y < height - 1:
                    row2.append(1)
                else:
                    row2.append(2)
        mrow += 2

def printMaze():
    for row in range(len(maze)):
        for col in range(len(maze[row])):
            print maze[row][col],
        print

def CreateWallRects():
    for row in range(len(maze)):
        for col in range(len(maze[row])):
            if maze[row][col] == 1 and row < 23:
                x = (start_x + col * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize) - 1
                y = (start_y + (row - 1) * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize)
                wallRects.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, 3, gsize)) 
            elif maze[row][col] == 1 and row == 23:
                x = (start_x + col * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize) - 1
                y = (start_y + (row - 1) * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize)
                wallRects.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, 3, gsize * 2))
            elif maze[row][col] == 2:
                x = (start_x + (col-1) * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize) 
                y = (start_y + row * gsize) + (0.5 * gsize) - 1
                wallRects.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, gsize * 2, 3))

def drawMaze():

    lineColor = 255, 255, 255

    for x in range(0, width, gsize):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (x, 0), (x, height), 3)    #line(Surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1)

    for y in range(0, height, gsize):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (0, y), (width, y), 3)

    wallColor = 0, 0, 0
    for wr in wallRects:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, wallColor, wr)    

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image, self.rect = assetloader.load_image("Tank.png", -1)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())
        self.dir = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.rows = pos[0]
        self.cols = pos[1]
        self.x = self.cols * gsize
        self.y = self.rows * gsize
 #       self.orig_image, self.orig_rect = assetloader.load_image(img_name, -1) 
        self.orig_rect.x = self.x
        self.orig_rect.y = self.y
        self.orig_gun_pos = self.orig_rect.midtop
        self.ammo = 5
        self.vel = [0, 0]
        self.dead = False

    def draw(self, screen):
        image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.dir)
        screen.blit(image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        oldCenter = self.rect.center

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = oldCenter
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_UP]:
            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = -1

               self.vel_y = -1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0

            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)

        elif keys[K_DOWN]:

            if (0 < self.dir and self.dir < 90) or (-360 < self.dir and self.dir < -270):
               self.vel_x = 1

               self.vel_y = 1
            elif (270 < self.dir and self.dir < 360) or (-90 < self.dir and self.dir < 0):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 1
            if (90 < self.dir and self.dir < 180) or (-270 < self.dir and self.dir < -180):
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = -1

            elif (180 < self.dir and self.dir < 270) or (-180 < self.dir and self.dir < -90):
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = -1

            if self.dir == 0 :
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = 1
            if self.dir == 90 :
                self.vel_x = 1
                self.vel_y = 0
            if self.dir == 180:
                self.vel_x = 0
                self.vel_y = -1
            if self.dir == 270:
                self.vel_x = -1
                self.vel_y = 0 

            self.rect.move_ip(self.vel_x, self.vel_y)

        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.dir += 5
            if self.dir > 360:
                self.dir = 0
        elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.dir -= 5
            if self.dir < -360:
                self.dir = 0    

        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

size = width, height = 500, 400
gsize = 25
start_x, start_y = 0, 0
bgColor = 255, 255, 255

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)#, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sample Sprite")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

p = Player(width/2, height/4, pos)

coll_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)

going = True
while going:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                going = False

        p.update()

        screen.fill(bgColor)

        p.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I know that the init function that I used for class Player contains four things `(self, x, y, pos)`, and I have `Player(width/2, height/4, pos)` to define where it gets placed right now - but it says pos is undefined. So what should I use to substitue or define "pos" somewhere else?

Right now, I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tinytanks3.py", line 375, in <module>
    p = Player(width/2, height/4, pos)
NameError: name 'pos' is not defined
```

Can someone please explain what to put for pos and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from your Player class's `__init__()` method that `pos` is an argument that you need to specify when you create an instance of the class.

It should be a 2-element tuple of integers whose entries specify the columns and rows attributes of the created player object. You can tell this from the fact that elsewhere in your `__init__()` method, you have references to `pos[0]` and `pos[1]`.

For example,

```
p = Player(width/2, height/2, (3,4))
```

will create a player object named `p`, such that `p.rows` = 3 and `p.columns` = 4.